# Override onStop everywhere?

Tags: java, android

**Intro:**
I have made a fadeout/fadein which fades out the opacity of all views. I want to animate this between switching activities. I now have to add the fadein/fadeout to every onStop/onResume in every activity.

**Question:** Is it possible to create a custom overridden onStop function and use that in every activity?

Comment: have a activity class whichoverrides the onStop(). Make your class extend that activity class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a base activity like this

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

..................
..................
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Do your stuff
    }
....................
...................
}
```

Now in every activity extend the base actiity like

```
public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely override the onStop() function.  Make an activity StopperActivity with onStop overrider

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}
```

In other activities, just extend this custom activity instead of Activity

Answer (score 0):

Create class **BaseActivity**

for example

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
   void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
       // your code here (Need to write only once for entire app)
   }
   void onStop()
   {
        super.onStop();
       // your code here of onStop (Need to write only once for entire app)
   }
}
```

And now use this **BaseActivity** for all your activities in your class.

```
class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
{
   ...
}
class AnotherActivity extends BaseActivity
{
   ...
}
```

In this way you will need to write code only once for fadeIn and fadeOut in BaseActivity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion rather than the answer to your questions.

Based on your description, it seems like you want to define a custom transition animation between activities. Why not just define a Style? All you need to do is define `windowExitAnimation`and `windoEnterAnimation` in your custom style, and then override `windowAnimationStyle`.

Check out the developer guide on how how to define your own style [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme).